# JWplayer - multiple players on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, flash, jwplayer

I have 3 videos on one page, however only the first loads.

I understand I must create a for each loop but am unsure how to go about it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

My page looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>


<div class="container">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "vid1.flv",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>


<div class="container">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "vid2.flv",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>


<div class="container">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "vid3.flv",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing `.` for the class selectors.

Comment: Yeah I couldnt find where the 'container' element was referenced to in the jwplayer.js so I coulndt change it

Comment: shoudn't you be using id instead of class?

Comment: @sylv3rblade yes tried both - same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the answer was simple... I just gave the divs individual names:

EG:

```
<div id="container1">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container1").setup({
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "vid1.flv",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>


<div id="container2">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container2").setup({
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "vid2.flv",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>
```

Comment: i have the same issue and use the "solution" you have as well but it's ridiculous. With 20 videos (the same video, 20 times on the page) the loading time is so slow and the page unresponsive until the players are initiated. This is not an acceptable solution. Searching for another one right now.

Comment: @Sumit Try the JQuery Lazy Load plugin. You can link it to an event if you like - I had about 20 YouTube vids on one page that took ages to load so linked Lazy Load to load them as the page scrolled

Comment: nah i ended up showing all videos in overlays, initiating them only when the overlay is opened.